# Why are my Angular routerLink buttons not working when using *ngIf with afAuth.user?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angularfire2

My app has a navigation bar with some links to different components. These buttons should only be visible if a user is logged in, and the user has verified their email. The routes to the components are also protected with an Auth Guard.

Here's my code:

**nav.component.html**

```
...
<a 
  *ngIf="(authService.fbUser$ | async)?.emailVerified"
  mat-button
  routerLink="component-1"
  >Component 1</a>
<a
  *ngIf="(authService.fbUser$ | async)?.emailVerified"
  mat-button
  routerLink="component-2"
  >Component 2</a>
<a
  *ngIf="!(authService.authState | async)"
  mat-button
  routerLink="login"
  >Sign in</a
>
<button
  *ngIf="authService.authState | async"
  mat-button
  (click)="signOut()"
>
  Sign out
</button>
...
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
...
export class AuthService {
  fbUser$: Observable<firebase.User | null>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.fbUser$ = this.afAuth.user;
  }

  get authState() {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }
...
```

**verified-user-guard.ts**

```
...
export class VerifiedUserGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.fbUser$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => (user && user.emailVerified)),
      tap(isVerified => {
        if (!isVerified) {
          this.router.navigate(['email-verification-pending']);
        }
        console.log(`Verified user: ${isVerified}`);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'component-1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./component-1/component-1.module').then(m => m.ComponentOneModule),
    canActivate: [VerifiedUserGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'component-2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./component-2/component-2.module').then(m => m.ComponentTwoModule),
    canActivate: [VerifiedUserGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), AuthModule],
  providers: [VerifiedUserGuard],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
...
```

EDIT: When the Component 1 or Component 2 links are clicked, nothing happens. The page stays the same.

I've been noodling with this for a couple of days and this is what I've found:

1) The auth guards are working, in that if the user isn't verified and they try to access a route via the address bar they're redirected to the email-verification-pending page.

2) If I remove the auth guards i.e. comment out `canActivate: [VerifiedUserGuard]` from the app-routing module the nav buttons work as normal.

3) If I change the *ngIf condition on the Component 1 and Component 2 links to match the Sign out link i.e. `*nfIf="authService.authState | async"` then the buttons work and auth guards work.

So I can't work out where I've gone wrong. It seems to be something to do with using afAuth.user in the *ngIf but I really don't know why.

EDIT: There are no console errors

EDIT: The routing in the child components is as follows

**component-1-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ComponentOneHomeComponent }];
...
```

**component-2-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ComponentTwoHomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "component-2" },
      { path: "child-1", component: ChildOneComponent },
      { path: "child-2", component: ChildTwoComponent },
      { path: "child-3", component: ChildThreeComponent }
    ]
  }
];
...
```

Comment: Does this work `return this.afAuth.authState;`?

Comment: @MaihanNijat - does it work where? It's working in the get authState() function with the *ngIf="authService.authState | async" condition if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes. Does it return true?

Comment: Yes it returns true

Comment: @rafello What do you mean by "not working"? Do they stay on the same page, do they go to the wrong page? Do the auth guards get fired and return the wrong result? Do they have the correct href in the html?

Comment: Good point. When pressed, nothing happens. On hover they show the correct url.

Comment: Have you put console.logs into your guard to see if they at least get triggered? Edit: actually, the `tap` would redirect if it was false, so forget that

Comment: Can you also show the routing in your child modules? The router is going to try to match against an empty path in those

Comment: @KurtHamilton added child route info.

Comment: So nothing weird going on there then. I think the next step has to be a live recreation using mock data...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209541/discussion-between-rafello-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but I was able to work around my issue.

I added a currentUser getter to the auth service:

```
get currentUser() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
}
```

Then added the auth service to the constructor of my nav component and used it like this on my nav links:

```
*ngIf="authService.currentUser?.emailVerified"
```

This solves my immediate issue. The downside being that as I'm not subscribing to an observable the component isn't updated when the user verifies their email address. I read on the angular fire issues on GitHub that you can't listen for changes on email verification though, so maybe this doesn't matter.